# Joomla backend: links get bugged and become inaccessible

Tags: caching, redirect, joomla, cloudflare

Sometimes, when I click on links at my administrator panel, and it fails, or I "close" the editing screen for some modules/plugins/components, etc...
After that I can't access to it anymore, it redirects me to the same page, but I'm not allowed to

[image]

> "You are not permitted to use that link to directly access that page
>   (#108)."

In order to get a "workaround" for this, I have to manually click the checkboxes for each item, and then click the "EDIT" button at the top of the screen

It turns even worse when the link bugged is one of the "admin menu" items... For example... if I wantH

Here's a video to show you how I behave, and how the bug appear

### http://goo.gl/vWYfbR

---

### Just for more information:

> I'm using 301 redirect for canonical URLs (non-www to www), i was
>   doing it through my [**htaccess**](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=AKVj7gmS) file but once I started to use
>   cloudflare, I made a rule for that instead: 
>   [image]

And these are the HTTP headers my website returns: at http://www.feedthebot.com/tools/headers/
Code:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
Date: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 17:13:31 GMT 
Content-Type: text/html 
Connection: keep-alive 
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d043b039e0059d56660ebbfb1f3553b361410714811916; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.shangri.us; HttpOnly 
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT 
Location: http://www.shangri.us/ 
Server: cloudflare-nginx 
CF-RAY: 169e37367bd5117d-DFW
```

---

### EDIT 2: Status error spotted: *303 - See other*

I've opened the console to see what happens behind the scenes of this weird behavior and I got this... 
[image]

---

This is driving me crazy! Because when the bugged link item is one of the admin menu items, like plugin manager, every time I want to click on it I get redirected to my homepage, kicked out from administrator panel :S

Any expert out there with any idea?

Comment: This question is about Joomla management, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=859009 you sure?

Comment: Look at my link, it's not the Joomla Forums it's the Joomla Q&A site on StackExchange.

Comment: @Frondor Joomla has two features which could be the culprits.. or both.  The checkin feature locks an items if someone is currently editing it.  The second feature is a check for all edit views to ensure someone isn't trying to access the link directly without navigating to it via the back-end interface.  It sounds like a third party extension is interfering with Joomla finishing the save process and removing the checked out hold.  You see any errors in your console?  Also, a MUCH easier way to check-in via administrators interface menu in bulk:  Site > Maintenance > Global Check-In

Answer (score 0):

Looking around a little online this doesn't appear to be a CloudFlare issue that I can see (the other reports say that it may be a Joomla module or extension issue. Have you tried the Joomla forums?

Comment: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=615&t=859009 sadly, they are useless most of the time, because nobody's willing to help on that community.
I was using Admin Exile, but anyway, I've disabled it and still getting the same error.
Weird thing is it gets "fixed" alone after some time, so I can bug links again ^^

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling all non-default extensions, and try clearing your htaccess file